# What rules are there for epic spells, if any?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, forgotten-realms, epic-tier

Back in older editions of D&D there were rules for designing epic spells using seeds and factors. These epic spells still exist in Forgotten Realms currently (1400 DR) so what are the rules for epic spells in 5e? Are there official rules for this already made?

Comment: I've edited the edition number out of the question title, since the first tag (which is the system tag for this question) will be displayed in page titles and google search results alongside the question title anyway.

Comment: @V2Blast here's a link to the relevant meta if you want to include it when you make such edits: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1346/23970. (I suggest doing so, if only because I like sprinkling mainsite with meta links in the hopes that more stackizens discover/engage with meta.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No official rules exist

There are currently no rules for creating your own spells. I checked the DMG, Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, Volo's, and Xanathar's. If you want to use the old rules or spells created with the old rules you will have to sit down with your DM to convert them as homebrew material

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation arguing over whether epic-level spells still exist has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84683/discussion-on-answer-by-dinomaster-what-rules-are-there-for-epic-spells-if-any).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Epic Level Handbook from 3rd edition:

> Epic Spells are considered 10th level for the purpose of Concentration checks, spell resistance and other determinations

The rule in 5e relating to spell levels is (PHB):

> Every Spell has a level from 0 to 9

This rule is unequivocal.

As a result we can conclude that Epic Level spells no longer exist in 5th Edition.

Comment: ..."are considered 10th level for...determinations" doesn't *precisely* say that their level is 10, but that does seem a bit of a quibble.